# Ionic tab animation not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework to create a mobile app. I am using the ionic template from ($ionic start myapp tabs). When I click on the tabs, I want the animation to be slide in from left or right. For some reason, I cannot get it to work on my local. I tried to look for codepen examples. I found this one
    https://codepen.io/calendee/pen/IAjoL

```
<ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7"></ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
 <ion-tabs class="slide-left-right">
```

I think the key to this code is these three lines. I also tried to replace class with animation, but nothing seems to happen on my local

On the codepen website, it appears to be a blank page for me.[image: Please refer to this image]

I am not sure if it is because of my local setting? Or what is going on? Hopefully, I describe myself clear enough.